# Kill a process that run in infinite loop

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I create a process from c++ code, that run a python script.

```
STARTUPINFO si = {0};
PROCESS_INFOMATION pi = {0};
LPTSTR cmdArgs = _T("cmd.exe /k python myScript.py");
CreateProcess(NULL, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

The script run in infinite loop, for example:

```
while (1):
    print("hello")
```

I want to kill the process but nothing really work.
I t ried `TerminateProcess()`, `taskkill` with `pid` - they report that process terminated but it still running.

How can I kill the process while it runnning?

Comment: if you have access to the code add external termination condition (like detection of semaphore or something IPC based)which is tested time to time and which can be set from another app ...also are you sure you are terminating the process you want? Do you have priviledges high enough for it?

Comment: what code? python? I cant change it.
Yes, Im sure about the specific process..

Comment: if you are on linux flavours try pressing ctrl+z where it is running
that kills the current process

Comment: Which Windows? process scheduling and maintanence is very different between different versions.

Comment: @skybunk winapi usually means Windows

Comment: Show us how you kill it with TerminateProcess.

Comment: @rety `TerminateProcess` used in my answer worked for me and simple `cmd` also with inf loop executable. Just a silly thing as I am no Python coder but does not Python script create another process/thread with different handle?

Comment: your error that you create `cmd.exe` process, which is senseless. you need direct create target process. and kill it, not cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LPTSTR cmdArgs = _T("cmd.exe /k python myScript.py");
CreateProcess(NULL, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

this code create `cmd.exe` process and it create `python.exe` process. question - for what create intermediate `cmd.exe` ?! you need direct start `python.exe`. use `"python myScript.py"` command line and start `python.exe` direct (if use unicode *W* api and empty application name - string must not be readonly (in your code it readonly - so you use *A* api, otherwice you got exception))

`TerminateProcess` not work - because you have handle of *cmd.exe* and you can terminate it. but not `python.exe`.

> taskkill with pid - they report that process terminated but it still
>   running.

of course - pid belong to *cmd.exe* and it terminated. but `python.exe` still runing.

so again - solution very simply - direct exec target process, without *cmd.exe*

Comment: you right!
not sure, I thought I have to open cmd to call python.. thanks!